# Add SimpleXMLElement Object to Array

Tags: php, arrays, object, simplexml, sitemap

I have and object array as displayed below. Im having trouble adding to this object array as i keep getting an error.
Here is how it is at the moment:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
  [url] => Array
     (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [loc] => http://jbsoftware.co.uk/
                [lastmod] => 2015-02-02
                [changefreq] => monthly
                [priority] => 1.0
            )
      )
)
```

Now to add to the end of this i am doing the following:

```
$note="
    <url>
       <loc>{$actual_link}</loc>
       <lastmod>{$date}</lastmod>
       <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
       <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>
    ";
    $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($note);
    $page[] = $sxe;
```

Which in turn provides me with this error....

```
Fatal error:  controller::generateSitemap() [<a href='controller.generatesitemap'>controller.generatesitemap</a>]: Cannot create unnamed attribute
```

Could anyone please let me know why i cannot simply add this onto the end of the current object array?
This one has really got me stumped.

Comment: SimpleXMLElement objects _are not arrays_, they just behave like arrays _in certain ways_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$page` is not an array (or an array-object that won't mean anything), it is an object (an instance of the  class). So you can't use the array methods with it. You can only use [available simpleXMLElement class methods](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php).

For your particular needs, simpleXMLElement doesn't offer any methods to append as a child an other simpleXMLElement instance. However you can use the [`addChild`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) method to build the subtree element by element:

```
$url = $page->addChild('url');
$loc = $url->addChild('loc', "{$actual_link}");
$lastmod = $url->addChild('lastmod', "{$date}");
...
```

`$url`, `$loc` and `$lastmod` are new simpleXMLElement instances.